# mathabx in PDF/A

Tags: fonts, pdf-a, mathabx

How can I apply the package `mathabx` for a PDF/A?
`pdflatex` produces a PDF from

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{pdfx}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
$\smile$
\end{document}
```

which is rejected by Acrobat's Preflight saying

```
Font is not valid
  Page 1: TeX-mathb 10 9.963 pt Type 1 embedded (as a subset)
    List of glyph width mismatches (PDF data versus embedded font data)
      999.8 versus 0 (0/0)
```

The sole font therein comes from `mathb10.pfb`.

When I provide the file generated by `mftrace --keep-trying --formats=pfb mathb10`
from the metafont sources, Acrobat's Preflight approves the PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first.  Acrobat DC approves the PDF as PDF-A/1b compliant while Acrobat XI rejects.

As it seems, the preflight tool in Acrobat XI is misled by the two trailing `%`-comments in the encrypted part of [`mathb10.pfb`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/mathabx/pfb/mathb10.pfb).

```
$ t1disasm $(kpsewhich mathb10.pfb) | grep -C 1 '%$'
 noaccess def
%
/Subrs 1 array
--
 noaccess def
2 index%
/CharStrings 258 dict dup begin
$
```

When these comments are removed, also Acrobat XI approves the PDF.
The following instruction patches the font locally.  A later `pdflatex` invocation will consider it.

```
t1disasm $(kpsewhich mathb10.pfb) | sed -e 's!%$!!' | t1asm -b | sponge mathb10.pfb
```

Strange matter…